# integer comparison in gurobi python constraints

Tags: python, optimization, gurobi

I am using python interface in Gurobi to solve a mixed integer problem. I need to create a binary variable (u) based on result of a comparison 
if (sum_i(y_i-x_i) ==sum_i(y_i)) then I want u=1
otherwise u=0

model.addGenConstrIndicator does this for binary comparison. I need a similar function or approach for integer comparison.

Comment: Are x_i and y_i positive numbers?

Comment: yes, they are positive.

Comment: It means if x_i>0, u=0 ow u=1.